# Automatic backup of brocade switch FC configuration

Tags: backup, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, brocade

What is the best way to set up automatic backup for switch FC configuration?

I have searched the web and came across https://code.google.com/archive/p/save-simply-your-san/ , but it looks like it runs on windows and hasn't been updated since 2009.

We have multiple brocade switch FC and would like to be able to save their configurations. The firmware version is often different. Even sometimes we have other vendors.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about just using good old Rancid?  Contrary to its name I believe it does support Brocade SAN switches (among many others).

Comment: I haven't seen any plugin for Brocade SAN FC switches, maybe someone has some here?

Comment: There are some options out there but I haven't tried them personally - https://github.com/dotwaffle/rancid-git/blob/master/bin/brocaderancid.in and some items in this thread: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/rancid/users/8905